# Standard way of making more concise code which is repeated in several Event Procedures

Tags: vb.net

I have been given the following:

```
Private Sub boldButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Bold)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
    updateView()
End Sub

Private Sub italicButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles italicButton.Click
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Italic)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
    updateView()
End Sub

Private Sub underlineButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles underlineButton.Click
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Underline)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
    updateView()
End Sub

Private Sub strikethroughButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles strikethroughButton.Click
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Strikeout)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
    updateView()
End Sub
```

Seems to me like a lot of repetition - apart from the small section of code after the `Xor` operator. Is there a standard technique I should follow when code in event procedures is repeated in this way?

Just create a single method that each event procedure calls with an argument for the button calling it and also a parameter of type FontStyle for the variable following 'Xor' ?

Comment: *Just create a single method that each event procedure calls with an argument for the button calling it and also a parameter of type FontStyle for the variable following 'Xor' ?*: **Yes** (but you don't need a parameter for the button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a side option to Jacoooobley's answer, fundamentally his is correct just a way that you could make it more dynamic and generic.

```
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click, italicButton.Click, underlineButton.Click, strikethroughButton.Click
  'This gets us a list of available font styles
  Dim fontStyles = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
  'This gets a style based on the name (text of a textbox) if it can, if it can't we get `nothing`
  Dim selectedStyle = fontStyles.Cast(Of FontStyle)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) [Enum].GetName(GetType(FontStyle), x) = sender.Text)
  'Check if this isn't nothing
  If selectedStyle isnot nothing
    'Call `MyMethod`
    MyMethod(selectedStyle)
  end if
End Sub

Private Sub MyMethod(style as FontStyle)

   Dim curFont As Font
   Dim newFont As Font
   curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
   If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
       'create the new font
       newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor style)
       'set it
       rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
   End If
   updateView()

End Sub
```

This means you don't need a new case or method if you add a new button.

Comment: Are you sure yours is an addition to Jacoooobley and not to the answer of MarcinJuraszek ? You are calling the method `UpdateButton` which makes me think you've got the names mixed up? Yours is really a third answer Luke ....more advanced than either of theirs - and "no" currently there is lots in this method of your that I do not **currently** understand.

Comment: @whytheq I corrected the answer for you. Also added some comments to explain what each line is doing :)

Comment: @Jacooobley - I `+1`'d your solution and put a positive comment. Your comment isn't something I've ever encountered before on `SO` and is really not welcome on this site.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is use a single method of a common name, and assign all of the event handlers to the same method. So you'd want the opening line of the sub to contain;

```
Handles boldButton.Click, italicButton.Click, underlineButton.Click, strikethroughButton.Click
```

After this, use the "sender" to determine which button has been clicked, therefore sending through the correct FontStyle.

Best way to do this would be a case statement.

The following code should work for you, and it has been minimized to two methods.

```
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click, italicButton.Click, underlineButton.Click, strikethroughButton.Click
   Select sender.text
     Case "boldButton"
        MyMethod(FontStyle.Bold)
     Case "italicButton"
        MyMethod(FontStyle.Italic)
     Case "underlineButton"
        MyMethod(FontStyle.Underline)
     Case "strikethroughButton"
        MyMethod(FontStyle.StrikeOut)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub MyMethod(style as FontStyle)

   Dim curFont As Font
   Dim newFont As Font
   curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
   If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
       'create the new font
       newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor style)
       'set it
       rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
   End If
   updateView()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Create single `Sub` using `FontStyle` as a parameter:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton(style as FontStyle)
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor style)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
    updateView()
End Sub
```

And use it in all 3 event handlers:

```
Private Sub boldButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click
    UpdateButton(FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub

Private Sub italicButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles italicButton.Click
    UpdateButton(FontStyle.Italic)
End Sub

Private Sub underlineButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles underlineButton.Click
    UpdateButton(FontStyle.Underline)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 an alternative to the other solution by @Jacooobley ...both seem ok; is there a definite reason why I'd use one of these solutions and not the other?!

Comment: First of all that select case statement is unnecessary, because it's already done by system to fire proper event handler.  And what even more important, his method requires the buttons text to be exactly as select cases.

Comment: @whytheq there is no need for four methods in total, when you could have two. The question was about minimizing code, and four methods is unnecessary opposed to one small case statement...

Comment: @Jacooobley is right - why handle with multiple events as above when you can handle with one, both are similar but this example is harder to maintain.

Comment: @Jacooobley - I think this solution is very readable - and the hard-coding of button text in your `Select Case` statement might not always be considered best practice